# UINavigationBar not appearing

Tags: ios

The `UINavigationBar` from `self.navigationController` does not appear. I set the top bar in the `IB` to 'Black Navigation Bar', it shows on the `IB` but still not appear on the device.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a storyboard? Then the navigationbar isn't showing because your rootviewcontroller isn't wrapped in a navigationcontroller

You can fix this by selecting the viewcontroller in your storybard, then press "Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller"

Answer (score 0):

Setting the top bar from the IB is only for visual purposes just so you know how to place other UI elements on the view controller. To set a navigation bar, either you have to drag it from the objects palette and place it in the view controller. Or embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController`.